# Looking IBM JAR Alternatives

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, migration, websphere

My current application that I work on uses IBM WebSphere 8.5. But going forward we have to migrate to Tomcat. Now out application uses four jars from the IBM installation.

```
com.ibm.jaxws.thinclient_8.5.0.jar
com.ibm.ws.sib.client.thin.jms_8.5.0.jar
was_public.jar
j2ee.jar
```

The last one I guess I may find easily. But what are the alternatives to the other IBM jars? There are some classes that are used from these JARs in the code base. Example:

```
com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity...
com.ibm.wsspi.webservices...
```

Any help in this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you using these classes for?

Comment: It would be easier if you would list the classes that you are using. Perhaps some of these JARs are not needed at all.

Comment: If I remove the JARs from my classpath in eclipse, I do see these missing class errors popup:
`TrustAssociationInterceptor`
`com.ibm.wsspi.webservices.Constants.RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY`
`com.ibm.websphere.wssecurity.callbackhandler.UNTGenerateCallbackHandler;`
`com.ibm.websphere.wssecurity.wssapi.WSSFactory`
`com.ibm.websphere.wssecurity.wssapi.WSSGenerationContext`
`com.ibm.websphere.wssecurity.wssapi.token.SecurityToken`
`com.ibm.websphere.wssecurity.wssapi.token.UsernameToken`

and a few others

Comment: If your application is using these classes then you have a substantial amount of work on your hands...

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. Didn't expect anything less! :)
But first I would need to find alternatives to these.

Comment: Instead of migrating to Tomcat you should consider migrating to WebSphere Liberty or it open source version - OpenLiberty. It is as lightweight as Tomcat but still supports full JavaEE, so you will not have to do so much changes in your application.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have the option TomEE, Wildfly. Tomcat, Jetty, GlassFish. That's it :( WebLogic is an option, but i know that will be voted down.
I was leaning towards WildFly and its a good application server, and i have fiddled around with it recently. But I would still need to decouple the classes with this IBM gibberish so that they work with the new server.